# Phased upgrade IWS 8.6 to 9.3 with Sysplex

Tags: workload-scheduler

Running SYSPLEX with sysid SXX1 and SXX2. SXX1 is running OPC controller and OPC tracker while SXX2 is running only OPC tracker. 
Planning to IPL only SXX1 to upgrade the version from v8.6 to v9.3 while OPC at SXX2 still running v8.6. Do you see any problem with this arrangement? 
Will only IPL SXX2 for OPC new v9.3 after a few days the S1M1 running with the new V9.3

Comment: edit correction: Running SYSPLEX with sysid SXX1 and SXX2. SXX1 is running OPC controller and OPC tracker while SXX2 is running only OPC tracker. Planning to IPL only SXX1 to upgrade the version from v8.6 to v9.3 while OPC at SXX2 still running v8.6. Do you see any problem with this arrangement? Will only IPL SXX2 for OPC new v9.3 after a few days the SXX1 running with the new V9.3

Answer (score 0):

workload scheduler for z/OS  is designed to support this scenario. So no problem is expected if you proceed as you described. Katiuscia Berretta (IWSz development)